# How to run Mysql 5.7 in cmd Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd

I want to run mysql in cmd without change dir to where the mysql.exe is.
So what i need to do to run mysql like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzL7o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your system PATH variable to include the direct folder that the mysql.exe is in. you can then start mysql from any directory.

Comment: where can i add PATH , i use win 10

Comment: Control Panel → System and Security → System → Advanced system settings → Environment variables